# phpMyAdmin dumps a varchar without quotes

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm dumping a set of results with phpMyAdmin because I need to import it in another table. One of the columns is a Varchar(150). In the dump file, the values of this column are written with no quotes, resulting in a syntax error when trying to import.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I've never heard of that, when exporting SQL. If you export CSV or another format using phpMyAdmin, you have the option to not enclose strings with quotes.